# Device token is not registered for ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I implement the push notification for ios.But the device token is get for ipad ,ios v 8.3 but when i install the app in iphone 6s plus v9.0 then deveice token is not registerd.I create the all certificate according to [this reference](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) but i get the notification in ipad but not get iphone .
So what is the problem.I can not find out.Please help me

```
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    //Right, that is the point
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
else{
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *token=[deviceToken description];
    token=[token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token=[token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    token=[token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    if (token != nil) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DEVICE_TOKEN"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    NSLog(@"token-->%@",token);
}

-(void)registerDeviceToken
{
    NSUserDefaults* errDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *regerr = @"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application";
    if ([[errDefaults objectForKey:@"ErrDesc"]  isEqual: regerr]  || [errDefaults objectForKey:@"DEVICE_TOKEN"] == nil) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device token not register." message:@"Please check in member center that you have valid provisioning profile for your app." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else{
        NSUserDefaults* statusvalue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *status = [statusvalue objectForKey:@"status"];
        NSLog(@"Status->%@",status);
        if ([status  isEqualToString: @"SUCCESS"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"No need to register!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?email=&regid=%@&app_type=utnews_v1&mobile=%@",webAPIURL,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DEVICE_TOKEN"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mobile_no"]];

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSLog(@"url-->%@",request.URL);
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if(error)
                {
                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
                }
                else if (data.length>0)
                {
                    NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Response string-->%@",responseString);
                    NSMutableDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                    NSString *parsevalue = parsedObject[@"status"];

                    NSLog(@"%@",parsevalue);

                    NSUserDefaults* statusvalue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                    // Store data in prefereances
                    [statusvalue setObject:parsevalue forKey:@"status"];

                    //  Save to disk
                    [statusvalue synchronize];
                    // NSDictionary *jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    // [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No response from server.Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please write down your code?

Comment: Do not use `IS_OS_8_OR_LATER`. There are proper ways to check if an API exists.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should add  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` in  `if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)` statement. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be solved your problem from version iOS 6 and greater. 
 `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` is Deprecated from `iOS 8.0.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if (IS_OS_EQUAL_GRETER_8) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSetting=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSetting];
}else{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
} 
#else

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];


#endif
```

Comment: Do not use IS_OS_8_OR_LATER. There are proper ways to check if an API exists.